# Can closed and on-hold questions still be commented on after being put on hold?

Tags: support, comment, on-hold-questions

If a question is on hold, can comments (not answers) still be posted? For example to help the questioner know what changes their question needs?

I'm a bit hazy about this and it's not answered in the Help section about on-hold questions. So I haven't knowingly attempted to leave comments on any of these (unless that happened in one instance where the question was put on hold just as I was posting my comment).

Thanks

Comment: If you can find the clickable invitation "add a comment" below the question, you're good to go.  As far as I know, only *deleted* questions (and answers) are disabled with respect to comments (and only people with reputation 10,000 or more can see them anyway).

Comment: @BarryCipra There are also [locked posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-posts/info) - AFAICT commenting isn't possible on such posts, either.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, ah yes, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to comment on "on hold" questions.

It is good practice to guide users towards improving their questions.

It is not  good practice to answer "on hold" question in comments, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is **not** good practice to answer "on hold" questions in comments.   That would essentially defeat the purpose for putting questions on hold until improved.